# How can I use textlab with lsp-mode in tex files?

Tags: flycheck

If possible, I want to use https://github.com/latex-lsp/texlab along with `lsp-mode` during editing tex files.

I was not able to manage how can I combine those.

`M-x flycheck-compile` does not show up `texlab` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](https://github.com/ROCKTAKEY/lsp-latex) shows a minimal
configuration for `lsp-latex`, which is more featured than `lsp-tex` module in `lsp-mode`.

If you need more tight control of `texlab` the above page shows all the
variables which can be modified/configured at lsp level.

If correctly installed, it will be shown as `lsp`, first checker in flycheck checkers list.